# Tests in jest with done fail when they should succeed (because a done failed in a previous test?)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a test that contains many `done` functions. I assumed that in the case of a failed test, only this test would be displayed as faulty. Now I notice that not only one test is displayed as faulty, but all following tests that contain `done` are displayed as faulty.

Why is this the case? This makes it difficult to find out the faulty test later.

This is successful

```
    describe('Map#isRotating', () => {
    test('returns false by default', done => {
        const map = createMap();
        expect(map.isRotating()).toBe(false);
        map.remove();
        done();
    });

    test('returns true during a camera rotate animation', done => {
        const map = createMap();

        map.on('rotatestart', () => {
            expect(map.isRotating()).toBe(true);
        });

        map.on('rotateend', () => {
            expect(true).toBe(false);
            map.remove();
            done();
        });

        map.rotateTo(5, {duration: 0});
    });

    test('returns true when drag rotating', done => {
        const map = createMap();

        // Prevent inertial rotation.
        jest.spyOn(browser, 'now').mockImplementation(() => { return 0; });

        map.on('rotatestart', () => {
            expect(map.isRotating()).toBe(true);
        });

        map.on('rotateend', () => {
            expect(map.isRotating()).toBe(false);
            map.remove();
            done();
        });

        simulate.mousedown(map.getCanvas(), {buttons: 2, button: 2});
        map._renderTaskQueue.run();

        simulate.mousemove(map.getCanvas(), {buttons: 2, clientX: 10, clientY: 10});
        map._renderTaskQueue.run();

        simulate.mouseup(map.getCanvas(),   {buttons: 0, button: 2});
        map._renderTaskQueue.run();
    });
});
```

All tests with `done` are fail if I change the first test

```
    describe('Map#isRotating', () => {
    test('returns false by default', done => {
        const map = createMap();
        expect(true).toBe(false);
        map.remove();
        done();
    });
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] - I can run two tests with `done` in one suite and have one pass and the other fail without any issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for asking. I can't actually reproduce a simple example. It is specifically about this test: https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js/blob/main/src/ui/control/geolocate_control.test.ts. I have built in `try/catch` to get around the problem described here; https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js/pull/565#issuecomment-950351107

Comment: We can't help you if we can't recreate the problem.